# How to perform addition of dates in calendar control using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, date, addition, calendar-control

I want to perform the addition of dates using the calendar control. Not finding the perfect code for this. Will you please help?

Comment: What would you expect the result of adding two dates to be?

Comment: I am developing a menstrual tracker website. Suppose the user clicked on the date which is 12-03-2021 on the calendar and another input is off for "how long is the menstrual cycle" so in this case, the user has to enter "Days"(integer) to get the next month expected date...So how to perform it??..... So that the result to be shown on another Calendar.